# Customize or override the css from jqueryUI

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

Well, I am trying create a web layout that I already have in mind. I have a header where I can create a set of tabs using jqueryUI. This is very easy and I already have it, I will show you a screenshot.
[image: Screenshot]

The html is there:

```
<div id="header"><div id="headerMenu"><!--headermenu is the tabs div --!>
  <ul >
    <li><a href="#tabs-edition">edition</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-export">export</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-settings">settings</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-edition">
    <p>Text</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-export">
    <p>Text</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-settings">
    <p>Text.</p>
  </div>
</div></div>
```

I want that this looks in another way, The tabs pane filling the entire main header (removing the white spacing), remove the rounded corners and customizing the css and color.

I know css enough for this changes, but I have serious dudes if there are a convection, a method, a general way to customize the jquery ui styles, (I suppose that developers in general not use the defaults styles and they have to changes).

Anybody can guide me about this topic?

Comment: Adding a useful resource, I think its more effective override the jQuery UI styles, this a good example of it! http://keith-wood.name/uitabs.html#tabs-min

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [Themeroller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/) to create specific changes you need and get the css required for it. It would probably be easier than trying to make changes by hand.

Themeroller is a part of the Jquery UI project.

Comment: Its a great option. Anyway I ser this límites un some changes. Thanks!